# How to re-visit a topic that has been addressed years ago?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Forgive me if this has been addressed before, but my search of Meta didn't turn up anything. I am wondering what mechanism (if any) exists for re-visiting a question that has been clearly addressed before, but relatively long ago. For example, the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946662/) has 599 upvotes, but it is 5 years old. The answer itself has a note regarding its age, but I'm unsure of the best way to ask this question again for an updated discussion of the issue.

Comment: The question is both extremely opinion based, and extremely broad.  It's not an appropriate question for the site.

Comment: I agree that the phrasing of the original question is opinion-based, but that was just an example of the more general phenomenon I'm asking about, which is revisiting an old topic. However, when I read the highly-voted answer, it doesn't strike me as very opinion-based at all.

Comment: The very fact that the answer is extremely opinion based, extremely broad, and also very time sensitive (yet another quality that makes it not an appropriate question for the site) are all reasons why these answers are no longer useful, and the fact that those qualities have made the answers not useful *is a big reason why these types of questions aren't appropriate here*.  You'll find that questions that follow the rules and don't merit closure are *much* more likely to stand the test of time.

Comment: For a non-subjective question, if it really becomes dated, re-asking it becomes easy.  The solution will fail to solve the problem, in a very objectively demonstrable way.  In such a case, you merely need to describe the problem, explain what happened when you used the solution presented, and why it didn't work.  An updated solution (accounting for whatever differences there are between your situation and the original question, whether it be based on time or other factors) that now works can then be provided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 1):

For users that have earned more than 75 reputation points, the best option to revisit an old outdated question is to add a bounty. This costs at least 50 points.

You can chose among several reasons for the bounty, and you can also add a message to explain exactly which direction the new answers should take.

[image: bounty reasons]

The bounty helps attract new answers in two ways:

- users that are interested in points, try to earn the bounty
- the question appears in the "featured" list (both globally, and also in all the relevant tags).

For the people with less reputation, the options are more limited, as they can't add bounties, or even add comments or edit the question directly. For them the only option is to ask a new question and reference the old one, explaining what is missing from there.

Comment: Please, please recommend this is not the process for off-topic questions. Currently, community can't close-vote off-topic questions with bounties. This adds more burden on mods if we take the (only possible) action of flagging.

Comment: @jpp A bounty cannot be added if the question has been deemed off topic, and there's a 2-day limit which should be sufficient for the worst questions to get closed.

Comment: I don't want to introduce Meta effect, but I could link to 5 questions (~20%) on the "Featured" tab of a tag I look at which I would like to close vote but can't.